# How to use same Facebook app id in many ios applications

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-login

How to use same Facebook app for different ios application. I'm using facebook graph api 2.0 and i refered [Nextpeer](https://developers.nextpeer.com/docs/view/ios) document. How to redirect the ios application from the  facebook application using a customized `URLscheme` like **fb39877767662comcompanynamegame**

Comment: Add comcompanynamegame in URL Scheme Suffix (Optional) and add any other there too. But I wouldn't recommend using the same app id in more than one app.

Comment: @WizKid i tried, but this working in safari browser(in simulators)... not in facebook application (i.e. in devices)